# Where should I call a method to use data from it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to call `getAlbums()` method so I can use the data from the get request and display album data on the client side. I don't know where to call it though. I tried to call it in `render()` but it creates an infinite loop.

Albums.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import AlbumCard from "./AlbumCard";

export class Albums extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { albums: [] };
    this.getAlbums = this.getAlbums.bind(this);
  }

  async getAlbums() {
    const {
      match: { params },
    } = this.props;
    console.log(params.id);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:4000/albums/${encodeURIComponent(params.id)}`,
        {
          params: {
            id: params.id,
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(`Returned album data from the server: ${res}`);
      this.setState({ albums: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container" style={{ color: "white" }}>
          hello
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Albums;
```

I wanna do something like this inside the div.

```
this.state.albums.map((album) => (<AlbumCard img={album.img}/>))
```

Comment: "_I tried to call it in render() but it creates an infinite loop._" Please update your code to show what you have tried and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**componentDidMount()** is the best place for making AJAX requests.

The componentDidMount() method will set state after the AJAX call fetches data. It will cause render() to be triggered when data is available.

**Here is the working example with componentDidMount()**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import AlbumCard from "./AlbumCard";

export class Albums extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { albums: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get( 
                `http://localhost:4000/albums/${encodeURIComponent(this.props.id)}`,
                { params: { id: this.props.id } }
            )
           .then(response => {
                  console.log(`Returned album data from the server: ${res}`)
                  this.setState({ albums: response.data })
                }
            )
           .catch(e => {
                   console.log("Connection failure: " + e)
                }
           )
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {/*   Code for {this.state.albums.map(item => )}  */}
            {/*   render() method will be called whenever state changes.*/}
            {/*   componentDidMount() will trigger render() when data is ready.*/}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Albums
```

**More information:**

https://blog.logrocket.com/patterns-for-data-fetching-in-react-981ced7e5c56/

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get an infinite loop is because you're calling setState in render. Here is what's happening behind the scenes:

1.`getAlbums` is called in the render method.

2.The function triggers `setState`.

3.setState causes re-render.

4.In the render method, getAlbums is called again.

Repeat 1-4 infinitely!

Here's is what you could do:

1. Create a button and bind `getAlbums` as a method to the onClick event handler.

2.Run `getAlbums` on ComponentDidMount like so:

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.getAlbums();
    }
```

Comment: There's no need for the async on componentDidMount, or the await. `this.getAlbums()` will do it.

Comment: Actually, you do need to mark `componentDidMount` as `async` if it's invoking an async function. I spun up a quick and dirty example for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-minsky-pl5k8?file=/src/App.js 

Try running the code without componentDidMount as async (:

Comment: In your example, yes, because you use return await. In his, no.

Comment: You're right! I missed that bit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

use componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount(){
getAlbums() 
}
```